# How do I get the ID of the document I just inserted into MongoDB? (API)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get the ID of the document that I just inserted into mongoDB. Here is the node.js code:

```
app.post("/groups/new", (req, res) => {
  const dbGroup = req.body;

  Groups.create(dbGroup, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      var id = dbGroup._id;
      res.status(201).send(id);
    }
  });
});
```

I have tried various things, like adding a group to the function:

```
app.post("/groups/new", (req, res) => {
  const dbGroup = req.body;

  Groups.create(dbGroup, (err, group) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      var id = group._id;
      res.status(201).send(id);
    }
  });
});
```

But that also does not work, so I tested if my even get the API response on the front end with:

```
res.status(201).send("test");
```

Which works perfectly fine. So I don't know why this doesn't work, because all the documentation says this is the way.

Comment: What is the agent that you are using?

Comment: Try ```console.log("group = ",group)``` to check how is the object

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a way to get the id. It may be not the most efficient way, because it sends all the data it gets but it gets the job done.

Backend:

```
app.post("/groups/new", (req, res) => {
  const dbGroup = req.body;

  Groups.create(dbGroup, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(201).send(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Front end:

```
axios.post("/groups/new", {
  groupname: roomName,
}).then((res) => {
  roomid = res.data._id;
});
```